# Oracle - insert only rows with column value which doesn't exist in table

Tags: oracle, where-clause, notin

I have two identical tables in Oracle (identical by structure) - table_temp and table_total.

I need to insert in table_total rows from table_temp based on following condition - only rows from table_temp with PLAYER_ID value which doesn't exist in table_total should be inserted in table_total.

Table_temp has 112 milions of records.

I tried many solutions but it took too long time to process so I stopped execution. This is my last try I stopped after 7 hours:

```
INSERT INTO table_total
SELECT * 
FROM table_temp 
WHERE table_temp.player_id NOT IN (SELECT player_id FROM table_total)
```

What is best/fastest solution for this? Indexing column is not acceptable solution...

Comment: Short of indexing, I don't see any obvious way to speed up what you have above.

Comment: Try "PL/SQL bulk loads for the forall PL/SQL operator", may be you will get better performance with this.

Comment: Please provide the execution plan for the statement. What are the sizes of both the tables in terms of # of rows and gigabytes

Comment: @astentx, I don't see any statement numbers in execution plan for this statement. I know what you want, but I don't see that numbers like usually...

Comment: @punky run `explain plan for <your statement>` and then `select * from dbms_xplan.display(format => 'ALL')`. This will show you the (estimated) number or rows and bytes to be processed

Comment: Without indexes, on 100+ million rows, no wonder it takes ages to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_total dst
USING table_temp src
ON (src.player_id = dst.player_id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (player_id, col1, col2, col3)
  VALUES (scr.player_id, src.col1, src.col2, src.col3);
```

Comment: Should it be faster than `insert` with anti join? I see no obvious reason